# Array of checkboxes in java

Tags: java, checkbox

I would like to have 6 checkboxes, and do some stuff after a botton is pressed do you have an example?

Also can an array of checkboxes be used?

I want to avoid:

```
Checkbox cb1 = new Checkbox("A");
Checkbox cb2 = new Checkbox("B");
```

I am doing something like:

```
 JPanel panel = new JPanel();
 JFrame frame = new JFrame("the title");
 final JTextArea txt = new JTextArea(20, 30);
 Button boton = new Button( "DO");
 panel.add(txt);
 panel.add(boton);
 frame.add(panel);
 frame.add(panel);
 frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 frame.setSize(500, 500);
 frame.setVisible(true);
 boton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            txt.setText("");

            /*
            How would be the logic of array of checkboxes

            if checbox[0] is active  do action 0
            if checbox[1] is active  do action 1
            if checbox[2] is active  do action 2
            if checbox[3] is active  do action 3
            if checbox[4] is active  do action 4
            if checbox[5] is active  do action 5

            if checbox[0] and checbox[1] is active do action 6
            if checbox[0] and checbox[2] is active do action 7
            if checbox[0] and checbox[3] is active do action 8
            etc... 
            */ 



       }
    });
```

Comment: Is there a increasing or decreasing pattern to the labels?  How are they stored or provided?

Comment: I guess if they are like a normal array (0 1 2 3 4 5) that would be ok

Comment: Your code doesn't describe what you want to *do* with the checkboxes.

Comment: inside the action listener, I would like to use 6 check boxes, but I really do not know how to write them, also, if an array can be used, How would the code look like

Comment: So if one of them is active do some stuff, if a combination of them are active do some stuff etc..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
    List<Checkbox> checkboxes = new ArrayList<Checkbox>();
    String labels[] = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"};
    for (int i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
        Checkbox checkbox = new Checkbox(labels[i]);
        checkboxes.add(checkbox); //for further use you add it to the list
    }
```

And then the List use it in your ActionListener to reference the checkboxes. You can also use an array if you like.

Comment: to add in the panel, I do? `panel.add(labels);` or `panel.add(checkbox);`

Comment: Also, çHow would you add a tag or textfield for each checkbox?

Comment: You can do it while you are iterating. For example for each checkbox it's own textfield. If that's what you mean.

Comment: Yes, I have done it, how would you reference the checkboxes something like `checkboxes.get(0)`, how to know if it is true or false? `checkboxes.get(0).getState()==1`

Comment: Checkbox checkbox = checkboxes.get(0); if (checkbox.getState()) { //do something }

Comment: How about: `for (int i = 0; i < labels.length; ++i)` instead of creating a separate int `numberCheckboxes`?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, have an array of `JCheckBox`, example:

```
JCheckBox[] checkBoxes = {new JCheckBox("1"), new JCheckBox("2"), new JCheckBox("3"), new JCheckBox("4"), new JCheckBox("5"), new JCheckBox("6")};
```

or

```
JCheckBox[] checkBoxes = new JCheckBox[6];
```

Then you will have to iterate through `checkBoxes.length` and instantiate it (if you didn't) and add your listener through `addItemListener()` and finally adding each checkbox to your `JFrame`.

I hope this helps.