# Get text of selected checkboxes android?

Tags: android, checkbox, android-activity

I have 5 checkboxes in my activity xml. I need to get the text of all the selected checkboxes.

One approach is to see if checkbox1 ischecked() and get the text.

```
    if(checkbox1.isChecked())
       { String text=checkbox1.getText().toString();}
```

and so on.

This becomes quite a lengthy process.

Is there any other approach I can use?

Comment: Check this out to get an idea http://stackoverflow.com/a/5541701/1127263

Comment: @Nabin are you talking about the toggle switch?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22986460/i-have-a-multiple-checkbox-but-i-want-save-only-single-checkbox-value-in-activit/22988038#22988038
follow my this answer it will help you

Comment: Did u get an answer ? I have the same question.

Comment: @PC. yes u can use an array or list of checkboxes and then loop through it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of basic suggestions:

1. You do not need to `==true` operation above so a simple `if(checkbox1.isChecked())` would suffice.
2. Store them all in an `ArrayList` so you can iterate as below:

   ```
   List<CheckBox> items = new ArrayList<CheckBox>();
   for (CheckBox item : items){
          if(item.isChecked()) 
             String text=item.getText().toString();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

```
CheckBox[] nameString = new CheckBox[]{Array1, Array2, Array3, Array4, Array5, Array6, Array7, Array8};

for (int i=0; i<=7; i++)
{
    if (nameString[i].isChecked())
    {
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), nameString[i].getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please consider adding a bit of explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than looping through all your checkBoxes to find which one of them is checked, you could simply create a **List** of **selected** items at `onCHeckedChanged()` or `onClick()`

```
If(unChecked)==>Add to List==> if(Checked) ==> Remove from list
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin sample code:

You can create an event and bind same event to all the check boxes, like

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/chk1"
    android:onClick="onCheckBoxClicked" ....


<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/chk2"
    android:onClick="onCheckBoxClicked" ....
```

MainActivity:

```
  fun onCheckBoxClicked(view:View){
    view as CheckBox

    if (view.isChecked){
        var msg = view.text.toString()
        Log.d("Checkbox", msg)          //printing in log
    }
```