# Get value or checked value in Checkbox & RadioButton - Fastest way?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently working a Survey App where user choose or fill up some form with CheckBoxes and RadioButton and it will save in Firebase Real-Time database eventually once the 'Finish' button is clicked. Now I have this lines of code where I need to duplicate this type of codes in order for me to recognize which RadioGroup and RadioButton I need to read and save. It's like a loop and lengthy process for me.

[image]

On these line (in switch), I'm going to duplicate this until **RadioGroup thirteenG**, and I know it's kinda frustrating for me.

[image]

This will be  the result once the button is clicked.

[image]

Now my problem is not an actual problem, I just wanna know and need a help on how do I make it shortcut or make it easy so that I wouldn't duplicate it anymore, you know what I mean, so that I will also save time and a line of code.

In short, the **fastest way to read a CheckBox and RadioButton value within the RadioGroup.**

Thank you so much, any help will be much appreciated. Thanks again and have a good day!

I have only tried case instead of else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

checkbox :
You can call isChecked() on a checkbox to get its status.

```
if(checkbox.isChecked){
//checkbox checked
} else {

}
```

radiogroup:

```
// get selected radio button from radioGroup
int selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

// find the radiobutton by returned id
radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);

// and you can get value from radioButton using radioButton.getText
Toast.makeText(MyAndroidAppActivity.this,
       radioButton.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick answer!

With that way, regarding the CheckBox, I can get the specific checked text value once the button is clicked?

And with that radiogroup, I would not use switch anymore?

I will try your code now...

Comment: UPDATE:

Your radiogroup works perfectly! Thank you so much! Now I'm working with the checkbox, I'm having a bit confused if is there a different code I need to add inside else and if except with my code.

Comment: as you like if you want leave it empty or you can make anything inside it, please accept my answer if it worked well.

Comment: I'm having a bit confused on what code should I add with your CheckBox code in order for me to get the checked (multiple) value from radiogroup. I added checkbox inside radiogroup. Thank you so much!

Comment: what the purpose of adding checkBox inside radioGroup, I really don't know if I understand you well but if you want to use switch for radioGroup and then put it inside checkBox to tack the values from radioGroup you can do it, if I misunderstand you please share your xml and your updating code to understand you.

Comment: I removed the radio group from checkboxes. Your radiobuttons code works great! Now my problem is only the checkbox; let say number 3 has a 6 checkboxes and the user checked 3 checkboxes. How do I read only the checked checkbox value and save the specific text to firebase. Cause what I'm using with my code is if(cb1.isChecked || cb2.isChecked || cb3.checked){} And what if the user choose 4 or 5 or 1 checkboxes, so I may have to use that if, else, and so on, lengthy process again. Thanks again much!

Comment: Your welcome, yeah really its lengthy process, for that you can see the answer here same as your problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24117079/get-text-of-selected-checkboxes-android , I think this solution will help you.